# Workflow for delivering code to a client using two git repositories (internal and external)

Tags: git, git-flow

I have a situation where the client will receive source code, under version control using Git.  Client wants the progress of weekly sprints to be tracked, diff'd and controlled into their repo.  Eventually, client personnel will also make commits into that repo.

My team (let's call internal team) is using Git as well, and the git-flow workflow.  So every **release** of the **internal** repo should translate into a **commit** on the **client** repo.  We don't want every commit on the internal repo to show on the client repo.

So my current thinking/solution is to have a script that uses rsync to copy the working directory from internal to client (on the local filesystem) then commit into the client repo.  This could be placed as a post-receive hook on the internal server or something similar.

The solution seems too clunky to me, and perhaps there are better ways to achieve what I need.  What are other thoughts?

---

**EDIT to include accepted solution:**

As Scott Weldon pointed on the accepted response, `git-merge` allows to do this in a good workflow.  However, to make it work, other flags are needed.  One is to allow git to effectively merge the two stories, and the second one to give the appropriate strategy for resolving the conflicts.

So, assuming the reference that I'm merging from the **internal** repo is `release/x.x.x.`, the flow is

```
git fetch internal
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories -s recursive -Xtheirs --squash internal/release/x.x.x
git commit
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use Git's ability to add and merge disjoint histories.

Add the internal repository as a remote to your external repository:

```
git remote add internal ssh://user@host/path.git
```

Whenever you do a release in the internal repo, do the following in the external repo:

```
git fetch internal
git merge --squash internal/master
git commit
git push origin master
```

This will create a single commit in the external repo that contains any changes from `internal/master` since the last merge.

From the man page for `git merge`:

> `--squash`
>
> Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), but do not actually make a commit, move the `HEAD`, or record `$GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD` (to cause the next `git commit` command to create a merge commit). This allows you to create a single commit on top of the current branch whose effect is the same as merging another branch (or more in the case of an octopus).

So without the `--squash` flag, the history from `internal` would be included in the external repo.

If you are using a version of Git >= 2.9, then you will also need to add the `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag to the `git merge` command, because Git will refuse to merge unrelated histories by default. See [Git refusing to merge unrelated histories](//stackoverflow.com/a/37938036/2747593).

Comment: Thanks @Scott Weldon.  I have used squash on a single repo, but never between two repos.  This is a nice approach.  What are your thoughts on setting this as a post-commit hook on the server?  Essentially I would like to minimize chances that by accident, a developer on the internal team sends unrevised code (through intermediate history) to the client.

Comment: @Juan That should be doable. If your server uses bare repos, you'll have to do a full checkout somewhere else on the server, but as long as you have shell access that shouldn't be a problem. Your `post-receive` hook for the internal repo could then update the external repo and merge when needed.